# use a blank class to identify elements or other tag

Tags: jquery, html

Can I use a "blank" class to identify common elements of the dom in order to perform operations with jquery? I know the tag Id and Name must be unique in the dom, but, if i need identified similar elements but not necessary with the same styling...
For example, in this scenario:

```
<section class="custom-section identify1"></section>
<section class="custom-section identify1"></section>
<section class="custom-section identify2"></section>
<section class="custom-section identify1"></section>
<section class="custom-section identify2"></section>
<section class="custom-section identify1"></section>
```

In this scenario `custom-section` styling the section and identifyX group similar sections...
¿is correct?
And now with jquery i can get all section with identifyX:

```
$(".identify1)
```

I know in html5 exist custom data atributte (Data-*) [custom data HTML5](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)
Can I use this tag for this functionallity?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use "dummy" class names, that don't actually have any styles defined in the CSS.

And the correct seletor would be `$(".identify1")`

Answer (score 1):

Yes the, data attribute selected would be beetter, then setting a CSS class for you jQuery selector.

Here is an example using the data-X attribute selecotr

HTML:

```
<p data-test="">Hello</p>
```

JS:

```
var text = $('[data-test]').text(); 
alert(text);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7cmnC/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's perfectly acceptable to use classnames like that.

A class name is used to designate similar groups of elements. So that fits right in.